# Implement a sub column/row in a table, purely with HTML

Tags: html

I've created this to do list page, using only html. They way I display tasks and sub tasks is like so.

[image]

If you notice on the sub task, the checkbox for completion is in the same column as the name of the sub task. How would I give the subtask checkboxes their own column like the task checkbox, but still keep the sub task checkbox and sub task name lined up with the "Name" column?

Here is the code.

```
<style>
 table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>

<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>
      <div>Name      

      </div>
    </th>
    <th>
      <div>Assigned To

      </div>
    </th>
    <th scope="col">
      <div>Due Date

      </div>
    </th>

    <th scope="col">
<!-- Add Detail, Edit, and Delete Buttons --></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<!-- ITEM -->
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td data-label="Select Row">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="options" />
        <span></span>

      </label>
    </td>
    <td scope="row" data-label="Item Name">Task          

    </td>
    <td data-label="Assigned To">Tyler Zika</td>
    <td data-label="Due Date">6/06/2016</td>
    <td data-label="High Priority">

        <button>          
        <span>High Priority</span>
        </button>
    </td>
    <td data-label="Add Detail, Edit, and Delete Buttons" >

        <button>         
        <span>New</span>
        </button>

        <button>      
        <span>Edit</span>
       </button>

        <button>          
        <span>Delete</span>
        </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!-- BEGINNING OF ITEM ACTIVITY -->
  <tr>
    <td data-label="Indent Row"></td>
    <td scope="row" data-label="Detail Checkbox and Name">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="options" />
        <span></span>

      </label>
      Sub-task 1          

        <p id="">Description about sub task</p>
    </td>
    <td data-label="Detail Name"></td>
    <td data-label="Detail Due Date">5/20/2016</td>
    <td data-label="High Priority">  

        <button>
        <span>High Priority</span>
        </button>
    </td>
    <td data-label="Add Detail, Edit, and Delete Buttons" > 



        <button>
        <span>Edit</span>
       </button>

        <button>
        <span>Delete</span>
        </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!-- END OF ITEM ACTIVITY -->

  <!-- BEGINNING OF ITEM ACTIVITY -->
  <tr>
    <td data-label="Indent Row"></td>
    <td scope="row" data-label="Detail Checkbox and Name">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="options" />
              </label>
      Sub-task 2
        <p id="">-Description about second sub task.</p>
    </td>
    <td data-label="Detail Name"></td>
    <td data-label="Detail Due Date">5/20/2016</td>
    <td data-label="High Priority">

        <button>
        <span>High Priority</span>
        </button>
    </td>
    <td data-label="Add Detail, Edit, and Delete Buttons" >



        <button>
        <span>Edit</span>
       </button>

        <button>
        <span>Delete</span>
        </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!-- END OF ITEM ACTIVITY -->
</tbody>
<!-- END OF ITEM -->
</table>
```

Comment: Just to clarify for myself - You want the sub-task check box to be in the first row where the first checkbox is?

Comment: No, I want the sub-tasks check boxes to have their own column.

Comment: I don't want the tasks checkboxes to mix with the sub-tasks checkboxes (be in the same column).

Comment: Tyler are you looking for something like this - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/grGaWV

Comment: @ntgCleaner I edited my post to make is clearer. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Tables, this is as close as we can get: https://jsfiddle.net/a8mo92mu/

I've added another `<td>` to each row that either has a checkbox or not.  If it does not, you can use the `:empty` CSS selector to style it any way you'd like.

Can you post a picture of what you want if this is wrong?  You say you want the name of the sub task lined up with the "name" column header, but you also want the checkbox to line up with other sub-tasks, but not mixed with the main task.  I think this is as close as we can get.

**UPDATE**

You can put a table inside a table!

I've updated the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/a8mo92mu/1/
I've made a new `<table>` inside of the row to have their own layout - You need to also use `colspan` to make a single column span across two or three spans.

Comment: Your jsfiddle is close. I want the sub-task name/description/checkbox shifted over. The jsfiddle you have still has the sub-task named lined up with the task name.

Comment: So, do you want the checkbox lined up with the name column? or the actual sub-task description lined up?  You said "**but still keep the sub task name lined up with the "Name" column?**"

Comment: I want two columns (one for the checkbox, the other for the sub-task nam and description) underneath the single "Name" column.

Comment: @TylerZika, Updated

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use following code

```
<style>
  table, th, td {
     border: 1px solid black;
  }
  p {
  display:inline
}
</style>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>
        <div>Name

        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div>Assigned To

        </div>
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
        <div>Due Date

        </div>
      </th>

      <th scope="col">
        <!-- Add Detail, Edit, and Delete Buttons -->
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <!-- ITEM -->
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-label="Select Row">
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="options" />
        <span></span>

      </label>
      </td>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Item Name">New Whiteboard

      </td>
      <td data-label="Assigned To">Tyler Zika</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">6/06/2016</td>
      <td data-label="High Priority">

        <button>          
        <span>High Priority</span>
        </button>
      </td>
      <td data-label="Add Detail, Edit, and Delete Buttons">

        <button>         
        <span>New</span>
        </button>

        <button>      
        <span>Edit</span>
       </button>

        <button>          
        <span>Delete</span>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- BEGINNING OF ITEM ACTIVITY -->
    <tr>
      <td data-label="Indent Row"></td>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Detail Checkbox and Name">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="options" />
        <span></span>

      </label></td>
            <td>
              Front-end Redesign

              <p id="">Description about sub task</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td data-label="Detail Name"></td>
      <td data-label="Detail Due Date">5/20/2016</td>
      <td data-label="High Priority">

        <button>
        <span>High Priority</span>
        </button>
      </td>
      <td data-label="Add Detail, Edit, and Delete Buttons">

        <button>
        <span>New</span>
        </button>

        <button>
        <span>Edit</span>
       </button>

        <button>
        <span>Delete</span>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- END OF ITEM ACTIVITY -->

    <!-- BEGINNING OF ITEM ACTIVITY -->
    <tr>
      <td data-label="Indent Row"></td>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Detail Checkbox and Name">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="options" />
              </label>
            </td>
            <td>
              Back-end Hook Up

              <p id="">-Description about second sub task.</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td data-label="Detail Name"></td>
      <td data-label="Detail Due Date">5/20/2016</td>
      <td data-label="High Priority">

        <button>
        <span>High Priority</span>
        </button>
      </td>
      <td data-label="Add Detail, Edit, and Delete Buttons">

        <button>
        <span>New</span>
        </button>

        <button>
        <span>Edit</span>
       </button>

        <button>
        <span>Delete</span>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- END OF ITEM ACTIVITY -->
  </tbody>
  <!-- END OF ITEM -->
</table>
```

Codepen- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/grGaWV